# How do I make a python program keep going/restart?

Tags: python

I want my program to keep running even after I enter the first input. My program looks like this:

```
import os
import sys

print("Hello Officer. Let's get started!")
speed = int(input("Enter car's speed mph: "))
if 70<= speed <=75:
    print("Warning: speeding camera in process!")
elif 76<= speed < 100:
    print("Issue $50 Fine.")
elif speed >= 100:
    print("Issue $100 Fine and pull car over!")
else:
    print("No Action")

os.execl(sys.executable, '"{}"'.format(sys.executable), *sys.argv)
```

---

When I run the program, I get this:

```
================================ RESTART: Shell ================================
```

and the program doesn't actually restart. How do I make it work?

Comment: `while` + `break`?

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the whole program in a while true loop.

```
while True:
   print("Hello Officer. Let's get started!")
   speed = int(input("Enter car's speed mph: "))
   if 70<= speed <=75:
       print("Warning: speeding camera in process!")
   elif 76<= speed < 100:
       print("Issue $50 Fine.")
   elif speed >= 100:
       print("Issue $100 Fine and pull car over!")
   else:
       print("No Action")
```